# Set dashboard filter via URL

Tags: dashboard

One of the great things about SF reports is the way you can set filter criteria through the URL using parameters like `pv0=my+criterion`.  **Is it possible to do this with dashboard filters?**

I tried adding `?filterCombo0=Sample+Owner+Name` to the page below, but it didn't do anything:

[image]

Comment: Ideas: [Ability to pass Dashboard filters by URL (?pv0= functionality in reports)](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gqzSAAQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Lightning Experience, this is possible, using fv0/fv1/... parameters in the URL.

[This](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dashboards_filter_url.htm&type=5) is the Salesforce documentation for it.

Answer (score 6):

Per Daniel's comment above, this is not currently possible but there's an [open idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gqzSAAQ) you can vote for.