# How to pass dashboard filter using visualforce

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

I have a requirement where i need to show standard dashboard on Account object using Visualforce. For that i am using Iframe concept and where need to pass accountid to view specific account. Salesforce has added the functionality to add filters to dashboards in Winter 12. It works fine using salesforce UI but not working if i pass from Visualforce. Any suggestion.

Example

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to either create a custom link for use on the sidebar that passes the account ID from the current VisualForce page to the Dashboard or create a Button and add it to your accounts page. The process for either one is pretty much the same.

Check the Help Section Under **USING CUSTOM BUTTONS AND LINKS** including the subsection on **Useful Custom Buttons and Links** and be sure to look at the detailed section underneath the latter on **Getting Record IDs** which you'll definitely want to read as I'm certain you'll need that information.

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to pass in a filter value to a dashboard using URL parameters. See this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4308/set-dashboard-filter-via-url?rq=1) for more details on the discussion. Go vote on the idea in [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gqzSAAQ).

Answer (score 0):

Can you not achieve something similar using embedded reports - here is the link

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_embed_showcharts_pages.htm&language=en_US