# Add value in dashboard filter using apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, dashboard

[image]

I have one filter criteria which gets changed for every report that I am using in my dashboard.

I checked about adding filter in dashboard. But a user needs to add the filter values manually.
I don't want to hardcode this values. Can I add this filter values using query, trigger, or apex code ?

Answer (score 0):

In Dashboard you can send your Parameter same as we send in report Like below

```
https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/lightning/r/Dashboard/01ZRM0000005jrv2AA/view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=Closed%20Won&fv1=Acme
```

In above URL `fv0` and `fv1` is parameter.

Same [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4308/set-dashboard-filter-via-url) already asked.

[Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddBlUAJ/ability-to-pass-dashboard-filters-by-url-pv0-functionality-in-reports) Delivered by salesforce.

Ref : [Filter Dashboards with URL Parameters in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dashboards_filter_url.htm&type=5)

Comment: @nikola-naumovski I hope this will solve your Problem