# Adding filter to dashboard using Apex or visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dashboard

We have a dashboard that we want to scale for all Accounts, currently it is based on one account. 
User should have the capability to see this dashboard for any account that he chooses

Is there any possibility / way to add filter to the dashboard grammatically using Apex or Visualforce?

Comment: Why don't you add this dashboard on Account page layout, this will automatically filter your account based data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can easily do this and in a very beautiful way instead of using salesforce dashboards. Try this framework which goes into a VisualForce page.

http://www.oyecode.com/2014/01/how-to-build-graphs-on-visualforcepages.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer Copied from [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/409766/29547) question.

In Dashboard you can add parameter dynamically.

```
https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/lightning/r/Dashboard/01ZRM0000005jrv2AA/view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=Closed%20Won&fv1=Acme
```

In above URL `fv0` and `fv1` is parameter.

Same [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4308/set-dashboard-filter-via-url) already asked.

[Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddBlUAJ/ability-to-pass-dashboard-filters-by-url-pv0-functionality-in-reports) Delivered by salesforce.

Ref : [Filter Dashboards with URL Parameters in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dashboards_filter_url.htm&type=5)